# Google sheet Query - Exclude the very last row

Tags: google-sheets, select, count, limit, google-query-language

I'm trying to write a query function that takes data in sheet A to sheet B, but I'm going to exclude the last row of data. Is there a way to do this filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A:C, "limit "&(COUNTA(QUERY(QUERY(A:C, "select *"), "select Col1"))-1))
```

[image: 0]

or in other words, if you know that whole query is 4 rows do:

```
=QUERY(A:C, "limit 3")
```